# Add content in Response object externally

Tags: java, servlets, wrapper, servlet-filters

I have a simple application which renders a jsp file into the browser after getting some data from a servlet.Now I want to add some data in the form of some HTML Tag into the response object coming out of the jsp.

I have made a filter and response wrapper which overrides the getWriter method by returning a custom PrintWriter as:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
public PrintWriter getWriter() {
  return new PrintWriter(sw);
}
```

Now I am able to retrieve the string from this response object using getString function

```
public getString(){
   return sw.toString();
}
```

And I am able to add the content in the string using

```
str.split("<tag where I have to add>");
```

But now I want to render this string into my Browser.

Will I have to create some other Wrapper object? Or please suggest any other way to achieve this.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overruling the existing writer of the response object.  You should keep a reference to that one and in the end write the final/modified content to that writer.